# c# and BLE - writing to a characteristic works only once

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I'm developing a Windows form program that must be able to write a value to a specific characteristic of a BLE device once every 3 minutes. I don't want the user to pick up the right device. Instead I want to select in code the right device.
I'm able to connect to my device and write for the first time the value, but the second write procedures throws an ​ `System.IO.FileLoadException` in `mscorlib.dll`.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
​
  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //var devicex=await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(new Guid("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")), new string[] { "System.Devices.ContainerId" }); //get all connected devices
            var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(new Guid("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")), new string[] { "System.Devices.ContainerId" }); //get all connected devices
            if (devices.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var device in devices)
                {
                    BluetoothLEDevice dev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
                    DevicePairingResult dpr = await dev.DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Encryption);
                    Debug.WriteLine(dev.ConnectionStatus);
                    var services = await dev.GetGattServicesAsync();
                    foreach (var service in services.Services)
                    {
                        //Debug.WriteLine($"Service: {service.Uuid}");
                        //service.Uuid.GetType();
                        var characteristics = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);
                        foreach (var character in characteristics.Characteristics)
                        {                        
                         var result = await character.ReadValueAsync();
                         var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(result.Value);
                         var input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                         reader.ReadBytes(input);
                         Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(input));
                         Debug.WriteLine("Characteristic Handle: " + 
                                    character.AttributeHandle + ", UUID: " + 
                                    character.Uuid);
                }
            }
```

The problem happens even if I try to read or get UUID and it happens only on a specific UUID (What I mean is that the first and second UUID are read even for the second time, while the third one for the second time causes the exception).

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Full stack trace is

```
Eccezione generata: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in mscorlib.dll
'WindowsFormsApp4.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApp4.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll' completato. Caricamento dei simboli ignorato. Il modulo è ottimizzato e l'opzione del debugger 'Solo codice utente' è abilitata.
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   in WindowsFormsApp4.Form1.<button1_Click>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Andrea\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp4\WindowsFormsApp4\Form1.cs:riga 182
```

The line that triggers the exception is:

```
var characteristics = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

and the exception gets triggered when the BluetoothCacheMode is set to Cached or Uncached.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace and message from the exception, and also highlight the line of code that causes it to be thrown?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve, but your exception is most likely caused by reading from a characteristic not supporting reading.
You have to filter on the read property.
This can help you on your way:

```
 foreach (var character in characteristics.Characteristics)
 {
   GattCharacteristicProperties properties = character.CharacteristicProperties;
                    if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Read))
                    {
                       var result = await character.ReadValueAsync();
                       var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(result.Value);
                       var input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                       reader.ReadBytes(input);
                       Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(input));
                       Debug.WriteLine("Characteristic Handle: " +
                                  character.AttributeHandle + ", UUID: " +
                                  character.Uuid);
                    }
                   // these are other sorting flags that can be used so sort characterisics.
                    if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Write))
                    {
                       Debug.Write("This characteristic supports writing.");
                    }
                    if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
                    {
                       Debug.Write("This characteristic supports subscribing to notifications.");
                    }

 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. Adding your control for read/write/notify access still triggers the exception once I try to access to a specific characteristic that can be read/written. In fact I always want to access to a specific characteristic (always the same) and I can do this for the first time that I run the program. if I add one more cycle access to this characteristic I get the exception.

Comment: No other suggestion? Is there anybody able to help, please?